# How to hide item from menu if user has not right to it in Admin Section?

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I have create a new customer role "SubAdmin" with limited admin permission , assign it to any customer . When customer is login in admin section , he see same menu as administrator while he have not access right to some pages .

When customer trying to open those pages , it give access denied messages . I want to display only those pages in menu for which customer has right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.3, you can set this in the admin section:

Configuration -> Settings -> General and Misc Settings -> Security tab, then check **Hide admin menu items based on permissions**

Answer (score 0):

based on UserRole provided by you, you can do it.

login as admin in administrator area. go to ACL Permission menu under Configuration section.

check or uncheck permission for perticular user role.

for more information, [Add new menu (hide menu)](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjuhZntmNLPAhXGsY8KHbFrCjAQFgg0MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lateshtclick.com%2Fblogpost%2Fadding-a-new-menu-item-in-admin-panel&usg=AFQjCNGQB2Xe63iFzR1hgrjSidGsZZJmrA&sig2=x9gzhZI5ySUqHqzJGQ7MQA&bvm=bv.135258522,d.c2I)